How to read and access an Excel file which has sensitivity label-restriction applied using NPOI in c#
I need to access an Excel file via code using C# and the NPOI package which has sensitivity label-restriction applied. I am getting an error:

ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException: 'EOF in header'    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams.InflaterInputBuffer.ReadLeByte()
at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.SkipUntilNextEntry()
at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream.GetNextEntry()
at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.Util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource..ctor(ZipInputStream inp)
at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream in1, PackageAccess access)
at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.OPCPackage.Open(Stream stream, Boolean readOnly)
at NPOI.Util.PackageHelper.Open(Stream stream, Boolean readOnly)
at NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook..ctor(Stream fileStream, Boolean readOnly)
at

Code:
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var contentType = workbook.GetProperties().CoreProperties.ContentType;
    workbook.Write(fs);
}

